# Timber Menu from Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, shortcode, timber

Is it possible to get menu items in a shortcode like [my_menu slug="1"].

Below is what I tried based on the [YouTube shortcode in the docs](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/wp-integration/#shortcodes)

```
<?php
// Called from within an init action hook in functions.php
add_shortcode( 'my_menu', 'my_menu_shortcode' );

function my_menu_shortcode( $atts ) {
    
    if( isset( $atts['slug'] ) ) {
        $slug = sanitize_text_field( $atts['slug'] );
        
        $args = array('depth' => 2,);
        $menu = new Timber\Menu( $slug , $args);           
    
    }else{
        $menu = 'Please Enter a Menu Slug';
    }

   
    return Timber::compile( 'shortcodes/my_menu.twig', array( 'menu' => $menu ) );
}
```

```
// my_menu.twig
{% if menu %}

    {{menu}}

   <nav>
    <ul class="nav-main">
        {% for item in menu.items %}
           <a class="nav-main-link" href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</nav>
    

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Timber Version 1. To output I use [my_menu slug="1"] but that breaks the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had `menu.items` when I should of been using `menu.get_items`.

The below works

```
<?php
// Called from within an init action hook in functions.php
add_shortcode( 'my_menu', 'my_menu_shortcode' );

function my_menu_shortcode( $atts ) {
    
    if( isset( $atts['slug'] ) ) {
        $slug = sanitize_text_field( $atts['slug'] );
        
        $args = array('depth' => 2,);
        $menu = new Timber\Menu( $slug , $args);           
    
    }else{
        $menu = 'Please Enter a Menu Slug';
    }
      
   
    return Timber::compile( 'shortcodes/mey_menu.twig', array( 'menu' => $menu ) );
}
```

and the twig file

```
{% if menu %}
   <nav>
        <ul class="nav-main">
          {% for item in menu.get_items %}
                <a href="{{ item.link }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </nav>
{% endif %}
```